# Expotential Growth/Decay - Problem Deriving Atmospheric Pressure Formula

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, exponential-function

I have a problem deriving the following formula:

$$\frac{dP}{dh} = k\left(\frac{P}{T}\right)$$

Using the following 'rule':  If $\ \dfrac{dA}{dt}  = kA\,$ then $\,A = A_0\left(e^{\,kt}\right)\,$ where $A_0$ is the value of $A$ when $t=0$.

The problem lies in the fact that it $P/T$, so I'm having a little trouble with that.

Comment: Are $k$ and/or $T$ functions of $h$ ?

Comment: Does $T$ depend on $P$ (for instance through the ideal gas law)? If so then you need to take that into account. If not then you can treat it as a constant.

Comment: @Nicolas T is a function of height, where from about a height of below 12km, temperature declines pretty much linearly from around 290K at the surface to around 210K at 12km.

Comment: @user2764359 Ok, so you must take care of this when integrating. Another important thing is that pointed out by Ian : is there any relation between $T$ and $P$ ?

Comment: @Nicolas No, in this case it is not.

Comment: OK, so you assume that $T$ is linear with respect to $h$. (It's not hard to find the coefficients from what you said). Then the resulting equation is separable.

Answer (score 0):

If I take the figures of your comment, then the (linear) function for the temperature is

$T(h)=-\frac{20}{3}h+290$

This expression can be inserted in your differential equation.

$$\frac{dP}{dh} = k\left(\frac{P}{-\frac{20}{3}h+290}\right)$$

Now you can seperate the variables and then integrate both sides.